# Dockerized Sysbench could not connect to Mysql

Tags: linux, mysql-8.0, docker

I'm trying to follow [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/severalnines/sysbench/) tutorial.

It does not give Mysql version requirements. So I'd tried to use Mysql 8.0.18 Community Server to connect to using those commands.

I've created what have been required inside of Mysql 8:

```
mysql> CREATE SCHEMA sbtest;
mysql> CREATE USER sbtest@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyPassword+1';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON sbtest.* to sbtest@'%';
```

Than created script file with the first command:

```
[root@host ~]# cat sbpreparing
docker run \
--rm=true \
--name=sb-prepare \
severalnines/sysbench \
sysbench \
--db-driver=mysql \
--oltp-table-size=100000 \
--oltp-tables-count=24 \
--threads=1 \
--mysql-host=192.168.1.200 \
--mysql-port=3306 \
--mysql-user=sbtest \
--mysql-password=MyPassword+1 \
/usr/share/sysbench/tests/include/oltp_legacy/parallel_prepare.lua \
run
```

and launched it:

```
[root@host ~]# ./sbpreparing
sysbench 1.0.17 (using bundled LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta2)

Running the test with following options:
Number of threads: 1
Initializing random number generator from current time


Initializing worker threads...

Threads started!

thread prepare0
Creating table 'sbtest1'...
FATAL: unable to connect to MySQL server on host '192.168.1.200', port 3306, aborting...
FATAL: error 2059: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb18/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
FATAL: `thread_run' function failed: /usr/share/sysbench/tests/include/oltp_legacy/common.lua:66: Failed to connect to the database
Error in my_thread_global_end(): 1 threads didn't exit
```

I could connect to the MySQL server from the same machine using command:

```
mysql -h 192.168.1.200 -u sbtest -pMyPassword+1
```

But sysbench couldn't. How could I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50169576/mysql-8-0-11-error-connect-to-caching-sha2-password-the-specified-module-could-n)

Comment: Yes, it helped, Thank you!
You could answer using that approved answer and I will approve it because of it solves this question issue.

Comment: You can self-answer too, providing the exact details of what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of mustaccio I've resolved the issue by following instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50333079/10854998) answer:

1. Removed a comment sign before the next string in `/etc/my.cnf`:

   `default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password`
2. Connected as root:

   `mysql -u root -pMyPassword+1`
3. Executed the next query:

   `ALTER USER 'sbtest'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'MyPassword+1';`

After following these instructions Sysbench successfully connected to Mysql 8 and executed all preparation tasks successfully.